# Accessing dynamically incremented variable JS

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with making a little game in JS.
There's a day counter that increments every seconds through `setInterval()`.
I would like to access the incremented variable `daycount` from inside the main `new_game()` function to trigger game events based on days that have passed.

Would appreciate if someone could help or point me in the right direction.

```
var day = $('#time');
var daycount = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#start').click(function () {
        new_game();
        $(this).addClass('disabled').html('Started');
    })
});

function time() {
    setInterval(function () {
        daycount++;
        day.html('Day ' + daycount);
        return daycount;
    }, 1000);
}

function new_game() {
    time();

    if(daycount == 5){
        alert('something');
    }

}
```

Comment: `day.html('Day ' + count);` should be `day.html('Day ' + daycount);` to start with. Secondly, you will only see if alert dialog if you click the start button when the daycount is exactly 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a callback function to `time()`

You can not return inside the setTimeout callback as there is nothing to return to.

Also as it stands now you are only checking `dayCount` when the `new_game()` is initialized....not each time it changes in the interval timer

```js
let daycount = 0,
  day = $('#day');

function time(callback) {
  setInterval(function() {
    daycount++;
    day.html('Day ' + daycount);
    callback(daycount);
  }, 1000);
}

function new_game() {
  function checkCount(daycount) {
    if (daycount == 5) {
      console.log('Is 5');
    } else {
      console.log('Not 5');
    }
  }
  time(checkCount);
}

new_game()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="day">
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be  `daycount` not `count` here  `day.html('Day ' + daycount);`

```js
var day = $('#time');
var daycount = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#start').click(function () {
        new_game();
        $(this).addClass('disabled').html('Started');
    })
});

function time() {
    setInterval(function () {
        daycount++;
        day.html('Day ' + daycount);
        if(daycount == 5){
            alert('something');
        }
        //return daycount;
    }, 1000);
}

function new_game() {
  console.log("new_game called ");
    time();
    
    

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time">...</div>
<div id="start">Click me </div>
```

Comment: Edited the count to daycount. Was an error on my side but it still doesn't work. How would I write it so I can use the if syntax described ?

Comment: @max.dng : put if condition inside `setInterval` updated my answer,

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the requested functionality:

- `clearInterval()` is added to prevent `setInterval()` from counting continuously.
- `<input>` is added so the user can set the end count.

**Details commented in demo**

### Demo

```js
var day = $('#time');
var daycount = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#start').on('click', function() {

    /* Assign counter as the timer() function
    || running every second.
    */
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    /* Define timer() function to display the
    || daycount increments as the value of
    || output#time
    || When daycount reaches the value of user
    || input of input#end, run the 
    || stop() function
    */
    function timer() {
      daycount++;
      day.val('Day ' + daycount);
      if (daycount === Number($('#end').val())) {
        stop();
      }
    }

    /* Define stop() function
    || clearInterval of counter() function
    || thereby stopping the count from going 4eva
    || log the count
    */
    function stop() {
      clearInterval(counter);
      console.log('Day ' + daycount);
    }

    $(this).addClass('disabled').html('STARTED');
  });
});
```

```css
button,
input,
output {
  font: inherit
}

input {
  width: 5ch
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<input id='end' type='number' min='0' max='999'>
<button id='start'>START</button>
<output id='time'></output>








<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```